# Is there a way to go programatically go to different home screens?

Tags: android, homescreen

I know that you can go to the home screen by doing this:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

However, is there a way to go to other home screens as well?

Other home screens as in the screens that you see when you slide left/right.

Comment: Define what screen you are looking for.

Comment: I mean the other home screens

Answer (score 1):

You need a class that extends Activity.

Then you can use `Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, OtherActivity.class)`

`startActivity(intent)`

Note that you can also go to other screens, such as Setting screens from your device, Wi-fi settings, etc.

Read more

[Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

[Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: I'm trying to go to other home screens, not other activities.

Comment: What do you mean by other home screens?

Comment: By home screens, I mean the different screens you see when you slide left/right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use explicit class names of a class that extends Activity in the Intent

```
Intent other = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
startActivity(other);
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear in my question. I'm trying to go to the other home screens.

Comment: Home screens are non standard and are custom built by the OEM's, so that's not a generic enough use case to be supported by the intent system.  For example, there's nothing from stopping a phone maker from shipping a home screen that has only 1 screen, and there's nothing stopping the user from installing a custom home screen with similar settings.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. Thank you for your help.